# Find the $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n$ of $u^3_n=-n(u_n+1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> For $n\geq 1$, consider the sequence $u^3_n=-n(u_n+1)$. Evaluate $$\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n$$

That is all the given and here is my incomplete approach:

Define $f_n(x)=x^3+nx+n$, $x\in \mathbb R$, $n\in \mathbb N$

Then $f'_n(x)=3x^2+n>0$

So $f_n(x)$ is increasing

Now $f_n(-1)=-1$ and $f_n(0)=n>0$

By Intermediate value theorem, there exists a unique solution $f_n(x)=0$

Let this root be $u_n$ and so we also get $-1\leq u_n \leq 0$

Now for $f_{n+1}(u_n)=u^3_n+(n+1)u_n+(n+1)=u_n+1 \geq 0 $

And $f_{n+1}(u_{n+1})=u^3_{n+1}+(n+1)u_{n+1}+(n+1)=0$ ( because of our assumption )

That implies $f_{n+1}(u_n) \geq f_{n+1}(u_{n+1})$ and since the function is increasing we get $u_n \geq u_{n+1}$

So $u_n$ is decreasing

Since I have $$-1\leq u_n \leq 0$$ and $$u_n \geq u_{n+1}$$

Can I say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n=-1$?

Also is there any other way around to find its limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $(u_n)$ is monotonic and bounded. So it has  a limit. If $u_n \to u\neq -1$ then $u_n^{3}=-n(u_n+1)$ tends to $\pm \infty$ (depending on whether $u+1 >0$ or $u+1 <0$) which is a contradiction. Hence, $\lim u_n =-1$.

Comment: If its limit equal $-1$ then $-1=0$ by substitute into the equation, could you explain me about this? I don't understand it here

Comment: You cannot say that $-n(u_n+1)\to 0$ just because $u_n+1 \to 0$. This is a limit in the indeterminate form $(-\infty) (0)$ and anything can happen to the limit of this product. For example, the limit of $(-n)(\frac 1n)$ is not $0$ even though $\frac  1n \to 0$. @user635988